# My vodka added beer became sweet!

Tags: beer, sweetness, vodka

in my country it's illegal to buy or sell alcoholic drinks.
so I started trying to make them at home.
I make vodka by distillation and it tastes good as any other vodka.
A few days ago I bought **non alcoholic beer** from store and it was **sugar-free** type (*which people who don't want get fat use*), I added some vodka to my **non alcoholic beer** (by simple calculation it should contain 9% alcohol).
today I opened a bottle and tasted it, it was **TOO SWEET**!

Someone, tell me how to get rid of this sweetness, and why is that? It taste like candy!
If anybody knows why this sweetness happens too it will help me.

Thank you so much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infusing with Hops worked for me. i want to tell you how much and how i exactly solved the problem. result will be about 9% beer.

1. infuse each 250 ml of 80% alcohol with 1 oz of dried hops.
2. let it soak for 3-5 days and then by using a fine mesh remove hops.
3. normal beer bottle size is 330 ml, so add 40 ml of infused alcohol to bottle and pour it up with sugar-free beer.
4. cap the bottle and enjoy later!

Answer (score 4):

Increased alcohol might contribute to the perception of sweetness.  See the answers to [At what alcohol level does alcohol start to contribute sweetness?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/at-what-alcohol-level-does-alcohol-start-to-contribute-sweetness).  Because people report different experiences with this, I tend to agree with [this study that associated differing perceptions of the taste of alcohol with certain genetic variations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25257701)

If you're mixing vodka with beer one drink at a time, like a cocktail, I'd suggest adding something bitter to offset the sweetness.  To keep the flavor beer-like, you could even infuse the vodka with hops before mixing.

Are you doing your own fermentation before distilling your vodka?  If so, you're only a small change in ingredients away from just making your own beer.

Comment: i really liked your idea about infuse with hops, and be sure i will try it.
i saw the question you mentioned, but there too nobody was sure what is happening, is there any special chemical reaction? is it cause of acidity? what percent of alcohol cause it? right now i don't do fermentation part, but i tested it before and it didn't work so nice, cause in my country you cant find beer or wine yeast, and only available choice is bread yeast, which taste bad for beer.

Comment: I dug up a PubMed link for a study I'd seen referenced that might explain the disagreement about the sweetness and edited it in.  It probably just comes down to how each person experiences taste.  Experiment with it and find something you like!

Comment: it's not just my idea, any friend who tasted it told me wooah! it is too sweet, sweetness is more than what someone could like it...

Comment: Is the sugarfree beer sweetened with some artificial sweetener? If so, that would taste pretty sweet.

Comment: @Frazbro i went to company for that kind of beer! they said it have no sweetness or sugar at all, and they removed any remaining sugar in this kind of beer